# Let $X_1...X_n \sim N(\theta,\sigma^2)$ and the prior distribution on $\theta$ be $N(\mu,\tau^2)$. Find the marginal pdf of $\bar X$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

First I found the joint pdf of $\bar X$ and $\theta$:
\begin{align}
f_{\bar X, \theta}(\bar x, \theta) &= \frac{1}{2\pi\left(\frac{\sigma \tau}{\sqrt n}\right)} exp\left(-\left(\frac{n}{2\sigma^2}\right)(\bar x -\theta)^2 - \left(\frac{1}{2\tau^2}\right)(\theta-\mu)^2\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi\left(\frac{\sigma \tau}{\sqrt n}\right)} exp\left(-\left(\frac{n}{2\sigma^2}\right)(\bar x^2 -2\bar x \theta +\theta^2) - \left(\frac{1}{2\tau^2}\right)(\theta^2 - 2\theta\mu +\mu^2)\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi\left(\frac{\sigma \tau}{\sqrt n}\right)} exp\left(-\left(\frac{n}{2\sigma^2}\right)\bar x^2 + \left(\frac{n}{\sigma^2}\right)\bar x \theta - \left(\frac{n}{2\sigma^2} + \frac{1}{2\tau^2}\right)\theta^2 + \left(\frac{1}{\tau^2}\right)\mu \theta-\left(\frac{1}{2\tau^2}\right)\mu^2\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi\left(\frac{\sigma \tau}{\sqrt n}\right)} exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left[\left(\frac{n}{\sigma^2} + \frac{1}{\tau^2}\right)\theta^2 - 2 \left(\frac{n \bar x}{\sigma^2} + \frac{\mu}{\tau^2}\right)\theta +\left(\frac{n \bar x^2}{\sigma^2} + \frac{\mu^2}{\tau^2}\right)\right]\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi\left(\frac{\sigma \tau}{\sqrt n}\right)} exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left[\left(\frac{n\tau^2+\sigma^2}{\sigma^2\tau^2}\right)\theta^2 - 2 \left(\frac{n\tau^2\bar x + \sigma^2\mu}{\sigma^2\tau^2}\right)\theta +\left(\frac{n\tau^2\bar x^2 +\sigma^2\mu^2}{\sigma^2\tau^2}\right)\right]\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi\left(\frac{\sigma \tau}{\sqrt n}\right)} exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{n\tau^2+\sigma^2}{\sigma^2\tau^2}\right)\left[\theta^2 - 2 \left(\frac{n\tau^2\bar x + \mu\sigma^2}{n\tau^2+\sigma^2}\right)\theta +\left(\frac{n\tau^2\bar x^2 +\mu^2\sigma^2}{n\tau^2+\sigma^2}\right)\right]\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi\left(\frac{\sigma \tau}{\sqrt n}\right)} exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\tau^2+(\sigma^2/n)}{(\sigma^2\tau^2/n)}\right)\left[\theta^2 - 2 \left(\frac{\tau^2\bar x + \mu(\sigma^2/n)}{\tau^2+(\sigma^2/n)}\right)\theta +\left(\frac{\tau^2\bar x^2 +\mu^2(\sigma^2/n)}{\tau^2+(\sigma^2/n)}\right)\right]\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi\left(\frac{\sigma \tau}{\sqrt n}\right)} exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\tau^2+(\sigma^2/n)}{(\sigma^2\tau^2/n)}\right)\left[\left(\theta - \left(\frac{\tau^2\bar x + \mu(\sigma^2/n)}{\tau^2+(\sigma^2/n)}\right)\right)^2\right] + [?]\right)\\
\end{align}

I also know that to find the marginal pdf I need to complete the square above (according to the comments) and find

$$f_{\bar X}(\bar x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{\bar X, \theta}(\bar x, \theta)  d\theta $$

How do I complete the square to show that $\bar X \sim N(\mu, (\frac{\sigma^2}{n}+\tau^2))$?

Comment: If you going to take that approach, then you may want to "complete the square" in the integral in terms of $\theta$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A faster way could be to say that this is equivalent to $X_i \sim Y_i+\Theta$ where the $Y_i \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ i.i.d. and independently $\Theta \sim N(\mu, \tau^2)$. You have  $\bar{X} \sim \bar{Y}+\Theta$

You then get $\sum Y_i \sim N\left(0,n\sigma^2\right)$ as the sum of independent normals, and $\bar{Y} \sim N\left(0,\frac{\sigma^2}{n}\right)$ as a rescaling of a normal, and so $\bar{X}  \sim  N\left(0,\frac{\sigma^2}{n}+\tau^2\right)$ as the sum of independent normals